# get WebView instances stored in a ViewAnimator

Tags: android, webview, viewanimator

I have some WebView  instances that i stored in a ViewAnimator programmatically. Firstly i constructed each WebViesw. Then i add them into the ViewAnimator

```
WebView webview = new WebView(context);
viewAnimator.addView(webview, index, layoutparams);
```

While a webView being added into the ViewAnimator, an AsyncTask instance is executed to load webpage from a specific URL.

My question, how can i get a webView from that ViewAnimator for a particular index value. I want to do some specific actions to the webView, such as reload or stop. I have done this way..

```
WebView currentWebView = (WebView) viewAnimator.getChildAt(index);
currentWebView.reload();
```

But the currentWebView returned null. Is that the right way to get webView instance from ViewAnimator? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `getChildAt()` return null, but as a workaround, you can maintain your own list of WebView. This is a stupid question, but are you sure your index is valid?